# Unable to start mvc4 webapp debugging, VS2012( Update 1, Update 2 CTP 3), Windows 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, iis-8

I a unable to start debugging mvc4 webapp. I am getting following error(s) while trying to debug the application.

If am trying to use IISExpress

[image: Using IIS Express]

And using the vs2012 debugging server

[image: using the vs2012 debugging server]

I have tried a few fixes i could find from the web, and here is some information that might be useful in targeting the problem

- I am running visual studio in administrator mode
- IIS express starts normally without error if i try starting it using `c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress /trace:error`
- I have changed the target platform value of "v4.0" to "v4.0.30319" in `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`
- I am using windows 8, IIS8 and `aspnet_iisreg` don't work, so iis is configured using `Turn Windows feature On or Off`
- I am using VS2012 Ultimate

It was working fine before I applied CTP 3 update and installed Git extension by Microsoft. I was unable to test it between applying update and installing Git extension, but could that be part of problem ?

My last resort would be re-installing vs2012 and that would be a painstaking task, installing visual studio all the updates and god knows what !!!

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: should talk to MS about this. Update 2 CTP isn't go-live yet.

Comment: I think it is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36539
Installed this only for git plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem and resolved with checking/unchecking the option for IIS express and restart Visual studio [image]

Answer (score 0):

it's a known problem. Check out here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758876/visual-studio-2012-unable-to-start-program-error-when-debuging-website-on-win8-ie#tabs

For me works opening a list of available browsers, choosing Browse With and doubleclicking Internet Explorer - then it works fine if you want to use IE, you can also debug with other browsers and you'll be fine :)